# Matching questions and answers from separate lists

Tags: python, list

I have a load of worded numbers as questions and need to add them to another round if the number of questions in a round is not at 10 because wrong answers from the previous round are added to the second round. I can add the questions to round 2 but how do I match the questions with the answers which are in a separate list? Or can I put them in the same list?

```
extraquestions=[]
extraanswers=[]

q30='two thousand and two'
a30='2002'
extraquestions.append(q30)
extraanswers.append(a30)

x = len(round2questions)
while x != 10:
    round2questions.append(extraquestions[random.randint(0,18)])
```

I have 19 extra questions

Comment: Better to use `while x < 10`. That way, if `x` somehow happens to be 11, your program won't run out of memory due to the number of items appended to the list. Also remember to increment `x`

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to group each question and answer with a tuple, so for example you would have `extraquestions = [('three',3),('twelve',12),...,('two thousand and two',2002)]`. Then you can append pairs `(question,answer)` to your `round2questions` list.

Otherwise, if you prefer to keep the two separate lists, I guess you can save the random index into a variable to get both the question and the answer with it. By the way, you shouldn't use that variable `x` in the loop condition, because it won't "refresh" with each `append`.

```py
while len(round2questions) != 10:
    i = random.randint(0,18)
    round2questions.append(extraquestions[i])
    round2answers.append(extraanswers[i])
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was thinking I wouldn't be able to turn in my assignment.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to loop a question up to 10 questions. I can ask the questions just need to loop it.

Comment: r = 0
    rc = 0
    rw = 0

    r2q = round2questions[r]
    r2a = round2answers[r]

    print(r2q)
    r2p = input('Convert this into a number')
    if r2p == r2a:
        r+=1
        rc+=1
        n+=1
        print('Next question')
    elif r2p != r2a:
        r+=1
        rw+=1
        n+=1
        print('Next question')

Comment: Better to use `while len(round2questions) < 10`. See reasons on my comment to the question

Answer (score 1):

I'm not to fond of while loops myself, there is nothing that a while loop can do that a for loop can't do better.

You can save some headache by changing the while loop to

```
for x in range(9):
```

Let me explain why this is better.  The while loop is good for your example, but as you start getting into more detail while loops have the problem that they can have the possibility never ending. Using a for loop you are give a specific break condition that will always get met at some point, unless your break point is len(someList) and you increment the list.
x will start at 0 at increment by 1 at the end of the loop,  when x hits 10 the loop is over.

If you use

```
while len(someList) != 10
```

What if the length of the list is never 10? Then the loop will never end.  The for loop works in increments, the while loop works in Boolean logic. Mostly while loops are stated:

```
while True:
    if "some variable" == "some condition":
        break
    else: 
        "perform a task"
```

Comment: The for-loop does not solve the problem either, because you have no enforced a hard iteration count where that value should have been determined by the number of items in the list already. You can remedy this by using `for x in range(10 - len(someList))`, this way the for-loop is still limited by the number of items in the list already

Answer (score 0):

Ummm. This is how I am putting your problem together:
1) You have a few worded numbers and answers:

```
round1questions=["two thousand and two", "one thousand and one"] # and more
round2answers=["2002", "1001"] # and more
```

2) From my understanding of your problem, in every round, TEN questions are asked and TEN answers are taken...
3) If any of the questions get a wrong answer, the wrongly answered question is asked again in another round.

So here is my solution to the problem:

```
questions=["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
answers=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
ans_correct=[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

#You can use this method to add "None" to the ans_correct list if you have many questions
#and you're too lazy to write so many "None"s.
'''
ans_correct=[]
for each in questions:
    ans_correct.append(None)
'''

while (False in ans_correct) or (None in ans_correct):
    for each in questions:
        if ans_correct[questions.index(each)]!=True:
            ans=str(input("What is the numerical form of %s?" %(each)))
            if ans==answers[questions.index(each)]:
                print("Correct!")
                ans_correct[questions.index(each)]=True
            else:
                print("Wrong!")
                ans_correct[questions.index(each)]=False
```

Basically, the code above will keep asking you the questions until all the answers are correct. If any of the questions are answered wrongly, they will be asked again.